# Android DialogFragment и AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, java

Добрый день.

Есть необходимость в использование AutoCompleteTextView внутри диалога DialogFragment,
но при установке адаптера

```
View v = context.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_location,null);
AutoCompleteTextView editCity = (AutoCompleteTextView)v.findViewById(R.id.editCity2);
if (names!=null)
    editCity.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(v.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, names));
```

Поле не реагирует и не выпадает список автозаполнения. До этого поле editCity находилось на разметки Activity - там все прекрасно работало.
Пробовал указывать в первый аргумент конструктора ArrayAdapter контекст Activity - результат тот же

Comment: Что такое names? Он точно не null?

Comment: names - коллекция строк для адаптера автодоплнения. Точно не null